# Why do my variable group variables have an empty value?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I set up a variable group called `secret-variables` and gave it access to my pipeline.

In my pipeline I use a variable template and inside that variable template I define the variable group. I pass the variables from the variable template to pipeline templates using template expression syntax.

`azure-pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  - template: pipeline-variables.yml

stages:
  - template: templates/myPipelineTemplate.yml
    parameters:
      mySecretVariable: ${{ variables.mySecretVariable }}
```

`pipeline-variables.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
  # secret-variables contain mySecretVariable
  - group: secret-variables
  - name: foo
    value: bar
```

Yet the value of `mySecretVariable` in `myPipelineTemplate.yml` is empty. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that variable groups do not support template expression syntax. Macro syntax needs to be used in stead, change the code in the stage to:

```yaml
stages:
  - template: templates/myPipelineTemplate.yml
    parameters:
      mySecretVariable: $(mySecretVariable)
```

This works because macro syntax is evaluated at runtime and template expression is evaluated at compile time.